# In two dimensions show that the divergence transforms as a scalar under rotations.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, vector-analysis, divergence-operator

The following problem is from the Vector Analysis Chapter 1 of Griffiths' *Electrodynamics*

> 1.17 In two dimensions show that the divergence transforms as a scalar under rotations.

[A question has been asked about this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454102/divergence-transforms-as-scalar-under-rotation-in-2d-intuition), and there is a solution there. However, I don't completely understand it and I'd like to know specifically why the reasoning below seems not to work.

Let $F$ and $R$ be the vector fields

$$F(x,y)=\langle f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y)\rangle\tag{1}$$

$$R(\overline{x},\overline{y})=\langle R_1(\overline{x},\overline{y}), R_2(\overline{x},\overline{y}) \rangle$$

$$=\langle \overline{x}\cos{\phi}-\overline{y}\sin{\phi}, \overline{x}\sin{\phi}+\overline{y}\cos{\phi} \rangle$$

where $f_1, f_2, R_1$, and $R_2$ are scalar fields and

$$\begin{bmatrix} \overline{x} \\ \overline{y}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos{\phi}&\sin{\phi} \\ -\sin{\phi}&\cos{\phi}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}\tag{2}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \overline{x} \\ \overline{y}\end{bmatrix}=T\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}\tag{3}$$

That is, $\langle \overline{x},\overline{y}\rangle$ are the coordinates of $\langle x,y\rangle$ when we rotate by an angle $\phi$, and this linear transformation has matrix representation $T$.

Note that

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \cos{\phi}&-\sin{\phi} \\ \sin{\phi}&\cos{\phi}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\overline{x} \\ \overline{y}\end{bmatrix}\tag{4}$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}=T^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\overline{x} \\ \overline{y}\end{bmatrix}\tag{5}$$

I think what we want to show is that $\text{div} F(x,y)=\text{div} H(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ where

$$H(\overline{x},\overline{y})=F(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\tag{6}$$

That is, $H$ gives us the value of $F$ in a coordinate system in which all previous vectors were rotated by $\phi$. At a point $(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ we expect the divergence of $H$ to remain the same as the divergence of $F$ at a point $(x,y)$.

$$H(\overline{x},\overline{y})=F(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))=\langle f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})),f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\rangle\tag{7}$$

$$\text{div}H(\overline{x},\overline{y})=\nabla\cdot H(\overline{x},\overline{y})=\langle D_1,D_2\rangle\cdot \langle f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})),f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\rangle\rangle\tag{8}$$

where $D_i$ is the partial differentiation operator relative to coordinate vector $i$. (I think the issue might be in this step (8)).

$$=D_1f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))+D_2f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\tag{9}$$

At this point I am not sure what the best way to compute these partial derivatives is, but I think I can use the total derivative of a composition as in

$$=Df_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\cdot DR(\overline{x},\overline{y})\cdot\langle 1,0\rangle+Df_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\cdot DR(\overline{x},\overline{y})\cdot\langle 0,1\rangle$$

where the notation $D$ means total derivative, which

$$=\begin{bmatrix} D_1f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})) & D_2f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial R_1}{\partial\overline{x}} & \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial\overline{y}} \\ \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial\overline{x}}& \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial\overline{y}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

$$+\begin{bmatrix} D_1f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})) & D_2f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial R_1}{\partial\overline{x}} & \frac{\partial R_1}{\partial\overline{y}} \\ \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial\overline{x}}& \frac{\partial R_2}{\partial\overline{y}}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix} D_1f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})) & D_2f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\phi} & -\sin{\phi} \\ \sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} D_1f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})) & D_2f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos{\phi} & -\sin{\phi} \\ \sin{\phi} & \cos{\phi}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\begin{bmatrix} D_1f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\cos{\phi}+  D_2f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\sin{\phi} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} -D_1f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\sin{\phi}+  D_2f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))\cos{\phi} \end{bmatrix}$$

$$=\cos{\phi}(D_1f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))+D_2f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})))+\sin{\phi}(D_2f_1(R(\overline{x},\overline{y}))-D_1f_2(R(\overline{x},\overline{y})))$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re proving the wrong thing. The correct setup is as follows: let $U,V\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be open sets, let $F:U\to\Bbb{R}^n$ be a $C^1$ vector field on $U$, and let $\Phi:U\to V$ be a diffeomorphism. Define a new vector field $H$ on $V$ as follows:
\begin{align}
H(y):=D\Phi_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}[F(\Phi^{-1}(y))].
\end{align}
Here, I’m using the notation $DG_a$ to mean the (Frechet) derivative at a point $a$ of the map $G$. In Matrix language (which is a can of worms by itself), this is saying you take the matrix $D\Phi_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}$, i.e the derivative of $\Phi$ at the point $\Phi^{-1}(y)$, and you multiply it by the column vector $F(\Phi^{-1}(y))$. In differential geometry jargon, this is the push-forward of the vector field $F$ by the map $\Phi$ (i.e you take a vector field $F$ defined on $U$ and you ‘push it forward’ to a vector field defined $H=\Phi_*F$ on $V$).

To make contact with your notation, you’re working with $n=2$, and your rotation $R$ (thought of as a linear transformation on $\Bbb{R}^2$) is my $\Phi^{-1}$. What you’re missing is the extra composition with $D\Phi_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}$ on the left. Without it, it’s like you haven’t modified the target space of the function $F$ to rewrite it in the rotated coordinates. Now, for simplicity, suppose $\Phi=A$ is an invertible linear map. Then, the definition of $H$ simplifies (because linear maps are their own derivatives at each point) to
\begin{align}
H&:=A_*F= A\circ F\circ A^{-1}.
\end{align}
Now, you can calculate easily using the chain rule that for each $y\in V$,
\begin{align}
DH_y&=A\circ DF_{A^{-1}(y)}\circ A^{-1},
\end{align}
and so by taking traces (which is how divergence is defined in these linear coordinates) and using the cyclic property of traces, we get
\begin{align}
\text{div}(H)&=[\text{div}(F)]\circ A^{-1},
\end{align}
or rearranging, $[\text{div}(H)]\circ A=\text{div} F$.
This is what you were meant to show

---

**Remarks.**

Strictly speaking, the general definition of the divergence is **not** the trace of the (Frechet) derivative, which is why I had to make the unnatural assumption of making $\Phi=A$ be a linear map. More generally, note that
by the chain rule and ‘product’ rule, we have
\begin{align}
DH_y(\cdot)&=D^{2}\Phi_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}\left[D(\Phi^{-1})_y(\cdot), F(\Phi^{-1})(y)\right] + D\Phi_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}\left[DF_{\Phi^{-1}(y)}[D(\Phi^{-1})_y(\cdot)]\right].
\end{align}
It is only if we now specialize to the case that $\Phi=A$ is linear, then the second derivative vanishes, and we can write the above equality as
\begin{align}
DH_y&=0+ A\circ DF_{A^{-1}(y)}\circ A^{-1}.
\end{align}
Now, you see algebraically where the linearity comes into play. But abstractly/differential geometrically, the correct way to think of the divergence of a vector field is **with respect to a scalar density** (or a volume form). This may be a little too much, so I’ll stop here.

Comment: although I wrote an answer telling you where you went wrong (your definition of $H$ is wrong), here’s a word of advice (take it for whatever you think it’s worth). You are learning about vectors and the accompanying “vector-calculus” in the most arcane possible manner by following Griffiths. I’d suggest just getting familiar with the basic computations (Cartesian, spherical, cylindrical) in his exercises, and ignoring all his discussion on vectors, components, transformation laws etc. The way he introduces things is the way people did things when they had no better option.

Comment: What I am actually doing is going through the entire Apostol, Volume II, and using the problems in Griffiths' Electrodynamics as a test of whether have learned the math well (my experience has been that the physics problems tend to be both more interesting and I learn more from them since I can interpret the math more than when I simply study the math, especially in electromagnetism problems). Is Apostol still arcane in you opinion? What would be your suggestion to gain the familiarity you are recommending.

Comment: @evianpring Do the problems in Griffiths, just not the first few ones about components, transformation laws and all that. The later half of chapter 1, and chapters 2,5,7 were great (3,6,8 are more advanced) for the most part. They give good practice and intuition with Stokes and divergence theorems, and you also learn classical E&M along the way which is definitely a bonus.

Comment: Regarding Apostol, I don’t have much familiarity, but doesn’t he only do 1-3 dimensional calculus? I think that’s unnecessarily limited; sure that’s where we can draw but learning it properly with sufficient generality makes much more sense conceptually, because often when we generalize, we can see the clear nature of the concepts. After studying Spivak’s calculus, I went straight into his Calculus on Manifolds, accompanied with Munkres, and I also learnt from Loomis and Sternberg (my favourite of the three, but it’s also more general).

Comment: but the two volumes by Bamberg and Sternberg is a slightly ‘watered-down’ version of Loomis-Sternberg’s ‘abstract’ book, and it is great. They treat differential calculus generally from the beginning with emphasis on linear algebra, they also introduce the very natural idea of differential forms early on (0,1,2-forms), and how their integrals work. Also, they treat many topics in physics (SR, optics, E&M, thermodynamics etc). So, if you’re disheartened by the abstractness of Loomis-Sternberg (don’t be, but if you are…) then try look at Bamberg-Sternberg.

Comment: I was under the impression that I would need to complete a course on analysis before going to Spivak´s book on Manifolds and Munkres. My plan was to study Axler´s Linear Algebra book, then an analysis book, and then Munkres and Spivak. Maybe I should try and jump in.

Comment: About Apostol, the theorems are for n dimensions, not just three dimensions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145509/discussion-between-peek-a-boo-and-evianpring).